# How to remove ADBannerView out from UIViewController in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, adbannerview

In my app, I had added the `ADBannerView` into the `UIViewController` by code

in .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *adBannerView;
```

in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 518, 320, 50);];
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBannerView];
}

#pragma mark - ADBannerViewDelegate
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"bannerview did not receive any banner due to %@", error);
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"bannerview was selected");
}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave {
    NSLog(@"banner action should begin");
    return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewWillLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"banner will loaded");
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"banner was loaded");
}
```

My app is normally, it can show the `ADBannerView`. But now, I want to remove the `ADBannerView` out of the `UIViewController`, then I removed all the lines of code about the `ADBannerView`. I can build my app, but it cannot run, the error msg is:

```
Could not instantiate class named ADBannerView
```

Please help me to remove the `ADBannerView`. Thank you.

Comment: are you using storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
if (!bannerIsVisible){
    //LOG_TYPE(@"AD show");
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    // banner is invisible now and moved out of the screen on 50 px
    //            banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            //LOG_TYPE(@"view height: %f",self.view.bounds.size.height);
            self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0,568-49-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);
        }
        else{
            //LOG_TYPE(@"view height: %f",self.view.bounds.size.height);
            self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0,480-49-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);
        }
    }
    else{
        self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0,1024-56-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    bannerIsVisible = YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(hideAD) withObject:nil afterDelay:6];
}
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
if (bannerIsVisible){
    //LOG_TYPE(@"AD error");
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    // banner is visible and we move it out of the screen, due to connection issue
//        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);
    bannerIsVisible = NO;
    [self performSelector:@selector(hideAD) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    //        [self performSelector:@selector(hideAD) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}
}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave{
//LOG_TYPE(@"Banner view is beginning an ad action");
BOOL shouldExecuteAction = YES;
if (!willLeave && shouldExecuteAction){
    // stop all interactive processes in the app
    // [video pause];
    // [audio pause];
}
return shouldExecuteAction;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{
// resume everything you've stopped
// [video resume];
// [audio resume];
}

- (void)hideAD{
//LOG_TYPE(@"Hide AD");
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
// banner is visible and we move it out of the screen, due to connection issue
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        //LOG_TYPE(@"view height: %f",self.view.bounds.size.height);
        self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0,568-49+50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);
    }
    else{
        //LOG_TYPE(@"view height: %f",self.view.bounds.size.height);
        self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0,480-49+50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);
    }
}
else{
    self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0,1024-56+50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
bannerIsVisible = NO;

[self performSelector:@selector(bannerViewDidLoadAd:) withObject:self.adView afterDelay:60];
}


-(void)viewDidLoad{
...
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        self.adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,568-49-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    }
    else{
        self.adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,480-49-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    }
}
else{
    self.adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,1024-56-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
}
[self.view addSubview:self.adView];
self.adView.delegate=self;
bannerIsVisible=NO;
self.adView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
....
}
```

Comment: The question is about removing the banner from the project, not animating it on or offscreen.

Comment: First thing, create an object in viewDidLoad, do not take a IBOutlet of AdBannerView. Next thing, you should try [self.adView removeFromSuperView]; . This will remove your ad.

Comment: Yeah, I want to remove the ADBannerView out of project, not removeFromSuperView.

Comment: Then remove IBOutlet of ADBannerView from your view controller if added and remove all code related to it.

Answer (score 0):

if you add `ADBannerView` in storyboard then remove the `IBoutlet` of ADBannerView and its `delegate`.

break connection of below figure for `ADBannerView`

[image]

remove `ADBannerView`from storyboard and your above code is perfect.

Your error as below.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the error is the same your error. But I don't add ADBannerView in storyboard, I just add by code. And then I remove all lines of code about ADBannerView and I get the error.

Comment: remove your Derived Data and Clean your project. after run project. may be working fine.

Comment: I removed the Derived Data and Clean project, but still error.

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.adView removeFromSuperView];
```